# iOS add compiled bundles to simulator

Tags: xcode, ios, simulator

I have built some bundles for my "Debug" profile from the command line. I can move these onto an actual device (using organizer), but I do not get how to add them to the simulator device when building from the command line. I have tried putting them in "build/Debug-iphonesimulator" but they do not show up in the iOS Simulator.

How is this correctly achieved?  (the reason I am not using the xcode gui is because I have a working batch script for several bundles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the bundles these location for iOS simulator

```
Users/USER_NAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/APP_NAME
```

But i didn't understand why do you want to do that. You can copy all the bundle in the xcode project and add the dependency. (That what i would do in normal scenario.)

Comment: I see, building them in batch did not create folders, I didn't want to create folders but I saw the path, thank you!